# multiple selectors with the same classes how to setup click function?

Tags: jquery

see the following jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/haq8jzg1/

I do not want every $('.blue') to toggle on click, instead, I only want the next $('.blue') to show.

```
$('.red').on('click', function(){
    $('.red').closest('.blue').toggle();
});

<div class="red"></div>
<div class="green"></div>
<div class="blue"></div>

<div class="red"></div>
<div class="green"></div>
<div class="blue"></div>

<div class="red"></div>
<div class="green"></div>
<div class="blue"></div>

<div class="red"></div>
<div class="green"></div>
<div class="blue"></div>
```

I've tried to implement `closest()`, `next()` and `nextAll()` without success.

Comment: Those are classes, not IDs. Also, the jQuery in your fiddle is different from what you posted in your question.

Comment: ^ Also show how you tried to use 'next()'.  I'm guessing you are using $('.red').next() in your handler, instead of using $(this).next() which will be relative to the one you clicked, rather than finding all of them and not having context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('.red').on('click', function(e){
  $(this).nextAll('.blue').first().toggle();
});
```

More robust solution-- will look past the clicked `.red` element and get all `.blue` elements-- then just pops off the first (nearest) element found and toggles it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.next()` x2:

```
$('.red').on('click', function(){
  $(this).next().next('.blue').toggle();
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/xn8n5bz5/)**

`$(this)` refers to the element you clicked on, where `$('.red')` selects all the elements with the class red.

Answer (score 1):

When you are inside the event handler, you should refer to `this` variable to access the dom element that triggered the event.

On the other hand, `next()` returns the sibling that comes right after the current one, so you should use `nextAll('selector')` to get all siblings matching the selector. In your case you only need the first match, so you should filter results with `eq(0)` to get the first matching element.

So finally your code should look like this:

`$('.red').on('click', function(){
  $(this).nextAll('.blue').eq(0).toggle();
});`

Answer (score 1):

You can chain `next()` twice:

```
$(this).next().next().toggle();
```

**Working Example:**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.red').click(function(){$(this).next().next().toggle();});

});
```

```css
div {
display: inline-block;
width: 40px;
height: 40px;
}

.red {
background: rgb(255,0,0);
}

.green {
background: rgb(0,127,0);
}

.blue {
background: rgb(0,0,255);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="red"></div>
<div class="green"></div>
<div class="blue"></div>

<div class="red"></div>
<div class="green"></div>
<div class="blue"></div>

<div class="red"></div>
<div class="green"></div>
<div class="blue"></div>

<div class="red"></div>
<div class="green"></div>
<div class="blue"></div>
```

---

**The Javascript equivalent of the jQuery:**

```js
var reds = document.querySelectorAll('.red');

function toggleNextBlue() {
this.nextSibling.nextSibling.classList.toggle('hidden');
}

for (var i = 0; i < reds.length; i++) {
    var red = reds[i];
    red.addEventListener('click',toggleNextBlue,false);
}
```

```css
div {
display: inline-block;
width: 40px;
height: 40px;
}

.red {
background: rgb(255,0,0);
}

.green {
background: rgb(0,127,0);
}

.blue {
background: rgb(0,0,255);
}

.hidden {
display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="red"></div>
<div class="green"></div>
<div class="blue"></div>

<div class="red"></div>
<div class="green"></div>
<div class="blue"></div>

<div class="red"></div>
<div class="green"></div>
<div class="blue"></div>

<div class="red"></div>
<div class="green"></div>
<div class="blue"></div>
```